# Close all workbooks opened by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel app which open another workbooks stored into the WBdata variable.

What I want it does is when I hit the close button [X] it closes the WBdata Workbooks then if my app is the only remaining workbooks opened, close Excel, else just close this workbook.

I tried this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.WBdata.Close False

    If (Workbooks.Count = 1) Then
        Application.Quit
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

But it seems that the before close event isn't the way to go because the Else part of the If will fire again the before close.

So I tried to juste put an If like that :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.WBdata.Close False

        If (Workbooks.Count = 1) Then
            Application.Quit
        End If
    End Sub
```

But it results that I have all the workbooks closed but not the Excel application. (Maybe because the application.quit is on the before_close event ?)

How can I properly close the WBdata then this Workbook, and close Excel if they were the only remaining workbooks opened ?

Comment: ThisWorkbook.WBdata.Close False I think this should just be ThisWorkbook.Close False and wbData.Close false would do wbData.

Comment: The WBdata is a public variable so I have to put ThisWorkbook.WBdata. Close False. I use it to close the WBdata before the main workbook. If I just use the ThisWorkbook.Close False, I will have my main workbook closed but not the WBdata workbook

Comment: Hi Maxime, Workbooks.Count will also include workbooks that open automatically with Excel, but might not be visible,for example PERSONAL.xlsb/.xlsm workbook. IF you run the code through the debugger, what count do you get with just one workbook visible?

Comment: Hi ! After the WBdata.Close, the Workbooks.Count give me 1 as expected